# Keeping the php loaded in the <div> even after clicking buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have got a file with a div #info

```
<div id="info"><input type="button" id="edit" value="Edit"  /></div>
```

I use this to load a php file in the div:

```
$('#edit').click(function(){
$('#edit').attr('disabled', 'true');
$('#info').load('edit.php');});
```

The php file('edit.php') being loaded contains a button which should send all the edited data from the forms to an update.php file through ajax and update user data.
So far it works fine.. the php file gets loaded in the div and shows the user content.
As i click the submit button, which is just a button(because i'm using ajax to pick up data) all the elements in the page dissapear and what remains on the screen is just the edit.php and it does not work.. can somebody explain why that happens? 
Thanks in advance..

PS: let me know if all the other scripts are required to be uploaded, just didnt want the question to be too long.